# Fast check of existence of an entry in a SQL database

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

Nitpicker Question:

I like to have a function returning a boolean to check if a table has an entry or not. And i need to call this a lot, so some optimizing is needed.

Iues mysql for now, but should be fairly basic...

So should i use

```
select id from table where a=b limit 1;
```

or

```
select count(*) as cnt from table where a=b;
```

or something completly different?

I think SELECT with limit should stop after the first find, count(*) needs to check all entries. So SELECT could be faster.

Simnplest thing would be doing a few loop and test it, but my tests were not helpful. (My test system seemd to be used otherwise too, which diluted mny results)

Comment: You want to be sure there is an Index on 'a' in either case.

Comment: @Brett: Really not enough info to say that.  If 'a' is an enumerated constant with 3 possible values, an index on it wouldn't increase performance.

Answer (score 3):

this "need" is often indicative of a situation where you are trying to INSERT or UPDATE. the two most common situations are bulk loading/updating of rows, or hit counting.

checking for existence of a row first can be avoided using the [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) statement. for a hit counter, just a single statement is needed. for bulk loading, load the data in to a temporary table, then use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) using the temp table as the source.

but if you can't use this, then the fastest way will be `select id from table where a=b limit 1;` along with `force index` to make sure mysql looks ONLY at the index.

Comment: +1 Using one statement has the added advantage of being transactional.  If you check for existance in a separate SELECT, the row might be added between your SELECT and INSERT.

Comment: Good advice for plain SQL, but i use an orm which doesn't do unique for my need so i had to do it in the application logic myself. And the seems to have no check for existence either.

So this a good answer, even if it is not the one i was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

The limit 1 will tell the MySQL to stop searching after it finds one row.  If there can be multiple rows that match the criteria, this is faster than count(*).

There are more ways to optimize this, but the exact nature would depend on the amount of rows and the spread of a and b.  I'd go with the "where a=b" approach until you actually encounter performance issues.  Databases are often so fast that most queries are no performance issue at all.